# Telerik Silverlight RadGridView event with Caliburn MVVM scenario

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, telerik-grid, caliburn.micro

I am using RadGridView and Caliburn micro to implement MVVM pattern. 
I am trying to get doubleclick event in RadGrid but its not working and C# code is not reachable. 
My code is as below:

```
  <telerik:RadGridView 
    Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MySearch}"
    cal:Message.Attach="[Event DoubleClick] = [Action GoToMySearch($this.SelectedItem)]"
    x:Name="gridSearch"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    BorderBrush="Blue"
    BorderThickness="1"   
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"             
    Height="300"  >
```

Comment: There is no event with the name "DoubleClick" in Silverlight, dunno if the Caliburn guys implemented one as a facade to the UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent (which has a click-count property).

Comment: any other event rather than "DoubleClick", i should try!

Comment: Why don't you try the single click first and see if your action can be called at all. See the docu for [UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)